# How would I convert Euler angle derivatives into an other angle sequence converntion?

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I am using a robot simulation and apparently they are using a different euler angle sequence (XYZ intrinsic) than I used for my robotic model (ZYX intrinsic).

Now I suppose this difference of conventions also applies to how angular velocities are represented. Assuming the simulation returns euler angle derivatives in XYZ intrinsic convention, how would I convert it to ZYX intrinsic ?

I have converted the angles so far using quaternions as a intermediate representation. However I am not sure if I can do the same for derrivatives ?

Comment: A similar problem is treated here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081609/given-tait-bryan-angles-x-y-z-intrinsic-how-can-i-get-tait-bryan-an/3081640#3081640

Comment: @MattiP. I suppose these conversion still apply to euler angle derrivatives ?

Comment: Angular velocities are vectors, so order does not matter.  They obey the law of vector addition which is commutative.

Comment: @Tpofofn, yes I guess so. However since what I am given are not exactly angular velocities but derivatives of euler angles, I wonder how the conversion works in this case.

Comment: Are you sure that the simulation is returning Euler Angle Derivatives?  That would be very unusual.  Internally a simulation would store angular velocities as body-fixed angular rates or as quaternion derivatives.

Comment: @Tpofofn, I am not sure, I am using VREP and this is what I derived from the only source I have found so far : http://www.forum.coppeliarobotics.com/viewtopic.php?t=6780.