# Equivalent Euler angles when changing the rotation order

Tags: rotations

Let's say I have rotation defined by 3 Euler angles: x, y, z.

The rotation order in this case is Y-Z-X. (Y then Z then X)

what would be the equivalent x', y', z' Euler angles If I force the order to be Z-Y-X?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Here is a very similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081609/given-tait-bryan-angles-x-y-z-intrinsic-how-can-i-get-tait-bryan-an